# Taking action after registering new user in Django

Tags: python, django

I want take some action right after creating a new User using UserCreationForm.
In this situation i need to create a new instance of Model which is in one-to-one relationship with this new User.
Please tell me how can i connect my code which will create this Model instance to the UserCreations form or to the register view.
I know that there is a save method in UserCreationForm which finally creates new User, but i do not know how to connect it to my code

this is how my view looks like

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MyUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = MyUserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {"form": form})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return the newly created user instance like this `new_user=form.save()` and then you can create another model based on this user

```
 if form.is_valid():
      new_user = form.save()
      YourModel.objects.create(user=new_user,....
      return redirect('login')
```

Answer (score 2):

i think signals could help you.

you can write a signal, to do something after a instance of model creates.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals